# Twilio SMS sandbox using C#

Tags: c#, sandbox, twilio

How do you use the Twilio sandbox mode with C#?  I have a ashx.cs file that I am using to write my code. Would I put it there?  If so, what does that look like?
There is no real great examples on their website on how to do this except for CURL and Ruby.

We are using TwiML to general an XML file tha t parses our data to send back and forth to the Twilio service.  We don't want to be charged every time we send a test text message. 
How would we set the Sandbox up so we could do some testing.
I found the Test auth Token and account Sid, but how do I use those?
We don't have them in our current application and we are specifying our .ashx page in Twilio to process our code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

So if you just want to test that your ASHX handler is generating the right results the easiest way to do this is to just fake a POST or a GET request to that handler.  This lets you simulate the GET or POST request that Twilio will make to your app when it gets a text message.

You can see the parameters that Twilio will pass to your app when it receives a text message here:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#synchronous

There are a whole bunch of ways to simulate these requests.  cURL is one of them.  If your ASHX is expecting query string values, you can also just load the ASHX directly in the browser and append those values in the URL.  If the handler is expecting a POST request, I used a chrome plugin called [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-rest-client/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb?hl=en) to make these.

Of course you can also [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to make just about any HTTP request.

The Test Credentials really are more for simulating the use of the REST API (programatically sending SMS messages).  I just wrote a blog post that shows how to use the test credentials to create integration tests:

http://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/05/automating-twilio-integration-tests-with-test-credentials.html

Hope that helps.

Devin

Comment: Thank you for the response @Devin. We really appreciate the support.  I was unsure if we could send text messages from a phone and get a response back through the test/sandbox.  This helps to explain that, that is not the case and it has to "fake" the SMS programmatically.  I appreciate the info.